# pygame.blit() is diplaying the text twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
size = width, height = 800, 500
display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Temperature Test")
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.ttf", 25)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue1 = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

while True:
        pygame.display.update()  
        for row in sensor.pixels:
            row.sort()
            print(["Temperature is: {0}".format(temp) for temp in row], 1, red)
            celsius = myfont.render("Temperature is: {0}".format(row[-1]), 1, red)
            #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0),celsius.get_rect())
            screen.blit(celsius, celsius.get_rect(center=(160, 240)))    
        pygame.display.update()
```

[image: text displays twice in the screen and it overlaps over changing text]

I don't why the display is not working according to the code

Comment: dont call pygame.display.update twice

Comment: What is `sensor.pixels` in this sample code? It looks like you're drawing the text twice on the screen. As the values are different, the sizes of the text fields are different and the centred rectangles don't match. You could try incrementing the y value each iteration.

Comment: @hippozhipos calling `pygame.display.update()` twice is *not* the cause of the problem. It's only effect is slowing the frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

To draw your text in different locations, you need to increment your y position every iteration, e.g.

```
y = starting_value
for foo in bar:
   screen.blit(foo)
   y += line_height
```

Here's a minimal example based on your code that shows how to render your text in different positions on the screen.

```
import pygame
# create placeholder class 
class FakeSensor(object):
    pass

# initialisations
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

size = width, height = 800, 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Temperature Test")
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.ttf", 25)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue1 = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
sensor = FakeSensor()
sensor.pixels = [[1, 2, 300.5], [1, 2, 311.2]]

running = True
while running:
    pygame.display.update()  # redundant
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(green)
    y = 240  # initial Y position
    for row in sensor.pixels:
        row.sort()
        print(["Temperature is: {0}".format(temp) for temp in row], 1, red)
        celsius = myfont.render("Temperature is: {0}".format(row[-1]), 1, red)
        # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), celsius.get_rect(center=(160, y)), 1)
        screen.blit(celsius, celsius.get_rect(center=(160, y)))
        y += 20  # increment Y position for line spacing
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit frame rate
pygame.quit()
```

Note: the extra initial `pygame.display.update()` function call is so you can confirm for yourself that multiple calls are unrelated to your original error.